# Breaking functions into several lines

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

OK. I need to document some product, which is in JS, but I'm a little clumsy with the languge. There are code blocks in the documentation and I need to break some lines (they have huge tails in PDF). In Python I can do the following:

```
foo(bar1,
    bar2)
```

Can I do so in JavaScript? What are general recommendations on breaking long lines in JS?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Have you looked at others code, such as how jQuery shows it in their documentation?

Comment: Well I haven't tried it since I'm not sure what exactly to try. My question is more for general recommendations, than only the case with functions. Although I do admit, that I haven't tried the latter.

Also thank you for jQuerry reference. It *could* be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you may use line breaks with commas as you have written. Here is an example from the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Code_formatting#Code_formatting).

```
// Parenthesis-aligned, one argument per line.  Emphasizes each
// individual argument.
function bar(veryDescriptiveArgumentNumberOne,
             veryDescriptiveArgumentTwo,
             tableModelEventHandlerProxy,
             artichokeDescriptorAdapterIterator) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No problem. Many companies use Google's style guides (and often modify to taste) as the default standard since many people are familiar with them. Here is a list of the style guides in various languages. https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do that with JavaScript. Like Python, JavaScript will understand the brackets. I personally recommend writing comments before or after a method, not within its definition. If you give your comments their own space, your code will become quite clear, however adding the comments inline can be quite messy.

Comment: The docs are not in the form of source comments, they are written manually and there are blocks of code given. Still, thanks.